# UITableView jumps and flickers when scrolling

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, flicker

I have a `UITableView` that displays cells with an image and some text. The data is requested on demand - I first ask for data for 10 rows, then for then next 10 and so on. I do this in `tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, willDisplay cell: UITableViewCell, forRowAt indexPath: IndexPath)`. The problem is that when I receive the data and need to update the `tableview` it sometimes jumps and/or flickers. I make a call to `reloadData`. Here is part of the code:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, willDisplay cell: UITableViewCell, forRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {

    DispatchQueue.global(qos: .background).async {
        if indexPath.row + 5 >= self.brands.count && !BrandsManager.pendingBrandsRequest {
            BrandsManager.getBrands() { (error, brands) in

                self.brands.append(contentsOf: brands as! [Brand])

                DispatchQueue.main.async { 

                    UIView.performWithoutAnimation {
                        self.brandsTableView.reloadData()
                    }

                }

            }
        }
    }

}
```

The height of the cells is constant returned like this:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {
    return 70
}
```

I am using Kingfisher to download and cache the images. Here is some more code from the datasource:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return brands.count
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: CellIdentifiers.ImageTableCell, for: indexPath) as! ImageTableViewCell
    let brand = brands[indexPath.row]
    cell.centerLabel.text = brand.brand
    cell.leftImageView.image = nil

    if let url = BrandsManager.brandLogoURL(forLogoName: brand.logo!) {
        let resource = ImageResource(downloadURL: url, cacheKey: url.absoluteString)
        cell.leftImageView.kf.setImage(with: resource)
    } else {
        print("Cannot form url for brand logo")
    }

    return cell
}
```

How can I avoid the flickering and jumping of the table view on scroll? I looked at some of the similar questions but couldn't find a working solution for my case.

Comment: More than a few things may do that. One of those is using automatic dimensions with mismatching estimated row heights. You may need to create height cache to avoid it. But in general try adding more information on what you are doing

Comment: @MaticOblak Thanks for the response. The height of the cells is constant. I updated my question.

Comment: If you are using storyboard/interface builder then turn off the automatic dimension of cells.

Comment: Still just try to also add the estimatedRowHeight method and return 70 as well. Alternatively I believe you can just set it as a property on table view. The thing is that when you are scrolled down and you call reload data the system will still try to optimize and call estimated height instead of the real one. By default I believe the estimated height is 44 so the table view may jump. (It may be something else doing it but I would really prefer if you first make sure this is not the case).

Comment: @MaticOblak Thank you for the suggestion and explanation. The jumping disappeared on providing `estimatedHeightForRow` same as `heightForRow`. The flickering stayed and was fixed by Josh Homann suggestion to call ` UITableView.insertRows(at:with:)` with `.automatic` animation instead of `reloadData`. If you put your comment as an answer I will upvote it, but I will provide the whole solution as a separate answer and accept it for clarity.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

To remove the jumping issue you need to set `estimatedHeightForRowAt` the same as your row height. Assuming you will have no performance issues you can simply do the following:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, estimatedHeightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {
    return self.tableView(tableView, heightForRowAt: indexPath)
}
```

Or if the cell height is constant you can do `tableView.estimatedRowHeight = 70.0`.

Why this happens is because table view when reloading will use `estimatedRowHeight` for the cells that are invisible which results in jumping when the estimated height differs from the actual. To give you an idea:

Let's say that estimated height is `50` while the real height is `75`. Now that you have scrolled down so that 10 cells are off the screen you have `10*75 = 750` pixels of content offset. No when reload occurs table view will ignore how many cells are hidden and will try to recompute that. It will keep reusing estimated row height until it finds the index path that should be visible. In this example it starts calling your `estimatedHeightForRow` with indexes `[0, 1, 2...` and increasing the `offset` by `50` until it gets to your content offset which is still `750`. So that means it gets to index `750/50 = 15`. And this produces a jump from cell `10` to cell `15` on reload.

As for the flickering there are many possibilities. You could avoid reloading the cells that don't need reloading by reloading only the portion of data source that has changed. In your case that means inserting new rows like:

```
tableView.beginUpdates()
tableView.insertRows(at: myPaths, with: .none)
tableView.endUpdates()
```

Still it seems strange you even see flickering. If only image flickers then the issue may be elsewhere. Getting an image like this is usually an asynchronous operation, even if the image is already cached. You could avoid it by checking if you really need to update the resource. If your cell is already displaying the image you are trying to show then there is no reason to apply the new resource:

```
if let url = BrandsManager.brandLogoURL(forLogoName: brand.logo!) {
    if url != cell.currentLeftImageURL { // Check if new image needs to be applied
        let resource = ImageResource(downloadURL: url, cacheKey: url.absoluteString)
        cell.currentLeftImageURL = url // Save the new URL
        cell.leftImageView.kf.setImage(with: resource)
    }
} else {
    print("Cannot form url for brand logo")
}
```

I would rather put this code into the cell itself though

```
var leftImageURL: URL {
    didSet {
        if(oldValue != leftImageURL) {
            let resource = ImageResource(downloadURL: url, cacheKey: url.absoluteString)
            leftImageView.kf.setImage(with: resource)
        }
    }
}
```

but this is completely up to you.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed explanation. Correctly if the image is not set if not needed the flickering disappears even when reloading with reloadData. Great answer.

Comment: this is giving error "cannot call non function type uitableview"

Comment: func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, estimatedHeightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {
    return self.tableView(tableView, heightForRowAt: indexPath)
}

Comment: @HarshThakur Most likely you are missing implementation of `UITableViewDelegate` on "self". Another option is that you are using older version of Swift.

Answer (score 1):

If you are appending data to the end of the tableView, do not call reloadData, which forces recalculation and redraw of all of the cells.  Instead use [UITableView.insertRows(at:with:)](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uitableview/1614879-insertrows) which will perform the appropriate insert animation if you use .automatic and leave the existing cells alone.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the suggestion. It helped to remove the flickering. The jumping was removed by Matic Oblac's suggestion to return `estimatedHeightForRow` that is same as `heightForRow`. I will combine both suggestions into a separate answer.